# Where can the ICAO recommendations be found?

Tags: icao, icao-sarps

ICAO issues recommendations/rules/statutes/something? that standardizes the regulations for international air travel world-wide.

What are these "rules" officially called and where can they be found?  Are they available on the internet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- ICAO publishes and maintains **19 Annexes** to the Chicago Convention. They pertain to all matters in aviation and provide the framework for national legislation in each of the member countries in the form of **Standards and Recommended Practices** (SARP).
- In addition to the 19 Annexes, ICAO also produces more detailed guidance in the form of **Procedures for Air Navigation Services** (PANS): PANS-ABC, PANS-OPS, PANS-ATM. These are also usually referenced by their Doc number: 2007, 8168, 4444, etc
- In addition to the PANS, for specific regions of the world ICAO publishes **Regional Supplementary Procedures** (SUPP) to incorporate regional variants/requirements.

Any ICAO contracting state may have local legislation different from SARP/PANS, but is obliged to notify ICAO of these differences. You will find these differences in the country's AIP section GEN.

Getting electronic copies of these documents is a bit more difficult.  ICAO [sells these documents](http://store1.icao.int/) for a very 'aviation' price. Some CAA's and institutions will provide [electronic copies in PDF form](http://dcaa.trafikstyrelsen.dk:8000/icaodocs/), but they will most likely be out of date and their legality is suspicious at best. Welcome to the world of international law.