# What are the ICAO PANS? What are their contents?

Tags: icao

There are how many I.C.A.O. PANS? What are their basic contents? I have tried a lot in internet, but could not find out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can the ICAO recommendations be found?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/where-can-the-icao-recommendations-be-found)

Comment: `what are their basic contents` not a duplicate IMO :)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This questions is specifically about the PANS, not the entirety of the ICAO SARPs

Answer (score 9):

ICAO Procedures for Air Navigation Services (PANS) are documents approved by the ICAO counsel and recommended to states for worldwide application. As such they attempt to make air navigation services uniform across the world.

There are six PANS:

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Air Traffic Management

(ICAO document 4444, a.k.a. PANS-ATM)

Specifies the actual procedures to be used by air traffic service units in providing the various air traffic services to air traffic.

---

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Aircraft Operations

(ICAO document 8168, a.k.a. PANS-OPS)

Lays down rules for designing instrument approach and departure procedures. Such procedures are used to allow aircraft to land and take off when instrument meteorological conditions (IMC) impose instrument flight rules (IFR).

---

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Abbreviations and Codes

(ICAO document 8400, a.k.a. PANS-ABC)

Is a list of abbreviations and codes commonly used in aviation.

---

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Aerodromes

(ICAO document 9981, a.k.a. PANS-ADR)

This details aerodrome licensing and Aerodrome Manuals

---

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Aeronautical Information Management

(ICAO document 10066, a.k.a. PANS-AIM)

The PANS AIM details the requirements for collection, management and provision of aeronautical data and aeronautical information. It specifies the procedures to be applied by AIM units in providing the various aeronautical information services to other states and aviation stakeholders.

---

#### Procedures for Air Navigation Services - Training

(ICAO document 9896, a.k.a. PANS-TRG)

PANS-TRG specifies the actual
procedures to be applied by training organisations when
providing training for aeronautical personnel.
It details ISD (instructional Systems Design and Systems Approach to Training (SAT) which enables criterion based and material dependent methodical learning

Answer (score 0):

Pans are some documents giving information about air navigation provide by council his role to make the application of rules concerning the air uniform across the world

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Could you please consider expanding your answer? As it stands now you are not adding much information to the already exiting one.